# Object to byte array skips data c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Writer
{
    public char[] FileSignature { get; set; }
    public UInt16 FileSourceId { get; set; }
    public UInt16 GlobalEncoding { get; set; }
    public UInt32 ProjectId1 { get; set; }
    public UInt16 ProjectId2 { get; set; }
    public UInt16 ProjectId3 { get; set; }
    public UInt64 ProjectId4 { get; set; }
    public byte Major { get; set; }
    public byte Minor { get; set; }
    public char[] SystemIdentifier { get; set; }

    public Writer()
    {
        FileSignature = new char[] { 'A', 'A', 'C', 'F' };
        FileSourceId = 0;
        GlobalEncoding = 0;
        ProjectId1 = 0;
        ProjectId2 = 0;
        ProjectId3 = 0;
        ProjectId4 = 0;
        Major = 1;
        Minor = 0;
        var system = "Test 1";
        SystemIdentifier = new char[32];
        Array.Copy(system.ToCharArray(),SystemIdentifier,14);
    }

    public byte[] SerializeToBytes()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        var m = SerializeToBytes();
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("DataFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
        {
            writer.Write(m);
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this code, I noticed that certain bytes are skipped when converting to a byte array and writing to file. Can someone please help me of how to make sure all the data members are converted and stored in the byte array and written to the file. I have also attached a screenshot of the created file.

You can see that only 47 bytes of the class data are written to the file instead of 58 bytes:

[image: You can see that only 47 bytes of the class data are written to the file instead of 58 bytes.]

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever                                                                                                             FileSignature = 4bytes
        FileSourceId = 2bytes
        GlobalEncoding = 2bytes
        ProjectId1 = 4bytes
        ProjectId2 = 2bytes
        ProjectId3 = 2bytes
        ProjectId4 = 8bytes
        Major = 1byte
        Minor = 1byte                                                                                                                                     SystemIdentifier = 32bytes

Comment: Please be aware that what you're doing is not constructing a file that will be correct in terms of it can be handled by Valve games, you're *not* constructing a file with a signature of AACF, you're doing binary serialization of a .NET class. If you want to construct a file with a specific file format, *marshalling* **may** be more what you need, but binary serialization is not suitable for this.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The AACF signature is just a sample signature, not the signature of the actual file that I am creating. Could you please direct to relevant information on how to go about constructing the file from a class object. I couldn't find relevant information. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Sorry, my mistake. I thought that it was C# equivalent of uint8. Edited the code. Thanks.

Comment: The only relevant test here is to `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize()` it. A formatter is allowed to add metadata and skip default values. Peering at bytes is meaningless.

Comment: How are you counting the bytes in the output file? Did you try populating the fields with non-zero numbers to see where they show up in the hex editor?

Comment: @bommelding There is no deserializer. The generated file is based on standard format that will be read by another software for rendering. So the file should have bytes correspoding to each property in the class. I was planning to manually remove the metadata from the file once the file is generated.

Comment: It is pretty obvious from the comments that you must not use BinaryFormatter.  The only possible way to read that file correctly is with BinaryFormatter.  "Remove the metadata" is not good enough, BinaryFormatter encodes data to make it smaller.  You must exclusively use BinaryWriter, ensuring you write the data in the order and with the sizes that the reading program expects.  Not terribly hard to do, there is not a large amount of data to be written.  Merely annoying.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - I am counting the number of bytes from the identifier "AACF"

Comment: @HansPassant, I am currently using binary writer as an alternate option. I will have 100+ member properties, so individually writing each property isn't an elegant solution. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @AbhilashHazarika I tried your code with non-zero numbers, some relevant data is placed _before_ AACF in my environment.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Based on the comments, I don't think I can use BinaryFormatter. Currently using binary writer and writing each property but it isn't ideal as I have many properties. Writing the whole object at once as a byte array is desirable.

Comment: @AbhilashHazarika and then you'd also have full control over the order of the output data.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Do you know of any way of how I can write the entire object in the order of the declared properties instead of individually writing each property ?

Comment: "There is no deserializer." OK, but then forget about [Serializable] too. Your only chance would be in [StructLayout] and marshalling but that is hard to get right. Using BinaryWriter is probably easier, it gives you much better control over padding etc.

Comment: @bommelding Using BinaryWriter for now.